# Rewriting in wordpress url

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

Yes we love to make the url more shorter ,more clean.

Lets say we have css url like this

```
xxx.com/wp-content/theme_name/css/my_custom_css.css
```

However i would love to display it like this

```
xxx.com/css/my_custom_css.css
```

So i think rewriting is best choice.

I created a plugin made a new file rewrite.php and included the file and inserted code in rewrite.php like this in that

```
<?php 
function my_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $non_wp_rules = array(
        'css/(.*)'  => 'wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/assets/css/$1',
        'js/(.*)'  => 'wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/assets/js/$1',
    );

    $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules = $non_wp_rules + $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules;
}

function my_flush_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_flush_rewrite_rules');
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_rewrite_rules');
?>
```

And I installed popular Rewrite analyzer . But i see no effect.

dunno where was the problem .

But when i use `$wp_rewrite->wp_rules` instead of `$wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules` It shows but obiously it is not what we want ??

Where is the problem :( this is actually creating too much problem :(

thanks :)

Comment: Check your `.htaccess` - that's where WP will put non-wp rewrite rules. More to the point though, why are you rewriting assets URLs? Seems like overkill to me!

Comment: @TheDeadMedic THats my bad :( i thought that plugin named monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer will show but it didn't showed . So i thought i was mistake but every thing was fine with that code :) . No problem In my codes . Checked htaccess and knew everything seems good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>From [this other answer on the WP SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/35118/20143)</strike>

```
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'roots_add_rewrites');

function roots_add_rewrites($content) {
    $theme_name = next(explode('/themes/', get_stylesheet_directory()));
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $roots_new_non_wp_rules = array(
        'css/(.*)'      => 'wp-content/themes/'. $theme_name . '/css/$1',
        'js/(.*)'       => 'wp-content/themes/'. $theme_name . '/js/$1',
        'img/(.*)'      => 'wp-content/themes/'. $theme_name . '/img/$1',
    );
    $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules += $roots_new_non_wp_rules;
}
```

TheDeadMedic provided a much better version of this function:

```
function wpse_208051_add_rewrites( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $path = str_replace( home_url( '/' ), '', get_template_directory_uri() );

    $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules += array(
        'css/(.*)' => $path . '/css/$1',
        'js/(.*)'  => $path . '/js/$1',
        'img/(.*)' => $path . '/img/$1',
    );
}

add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'wpse_208051_add_rewrites' );
```

Comment: Hey @phatskat can we use wp_get_theme() instead of that next explad etc?? seems like we are overkilling isn't it?

Comment: @stlawrance  I'm sure you can :D This snippet was from another theme, and they probably wrote it to work that way for a specific reason. If you have a method that works for you, go for it!

Comment: Yes your solution seems correct :) the problem was that i thought monkeyman rewrite plugin will display it :) but it didn't show.. how ever from comment i looked htacess it was working as it should :)

Answer (score 1):

Following @phatskat's answer, this is what I would suggest. The biggest issue with the other solutions are the assumption of pathnames, which is a big no-no in WordPress development (especially those that are intended to be distributed to the public).

```
function wpse_208051_add_rewrites( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $path = str_replace( home_url( '/' ), '', get_template_directory_uri() );

    $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules += array(
        'css/(.*)' => $path . '/css/$1',
        'js/(.*)'  => $path . '/js/$1',
        'img/(.*)' => $path . '/img/$1',
    );
}

add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'wpse_208051_add_rewrites' );
```

Comment: Excellent! This should definitely be the accepted answer